# Javascript reduce gives incorrect values

Tags: javascript, lodash

Consider the data to be

```
{
    "Groceries": [
        {
            "category": {
                "uri": "/categories/20fe3330-80e1-4908-9f57-5b7ef575b197",
                "parent": "Food & Drink",
                "name": "Groceries"
            },
            "amount": "85.14",
            "debit": true
        },
        {
            "category": {
                "uri": "/categories/20fe3330-80e1-4908-9f57-5b7ef575b197",
                "parent": "Food & Drink",
                "name": "Groceries"
            },
            "amount": "19.15",
            "debit": true
        },
        {
            "category": {
                "uri": "/categories/20fe3330-80e1-4908-9f57-5b7ef575b197",
                "parent": "Food & Drink",
                "name": "Groceries"
            },
            "amount": "4.2",
            "debit": true
        },
        {
            "category": {
                "uri": "/categories/20fe3330-80e1-4908-9f57-5b7ef575b197",
                "parent": "Food & Drink",
                "name": "Groceries"
            },
            "amount": "16.08",
            "debit": true
        },
        {
            "category": {
                "uri": "/categories/20fe3330-80e1-4908-9f57-5b7ef575b197",
                "parent": "Food & Drink",
                "name": "Groceries"
            },
            "amount": "28.48",
            "debit": true
        },
        {
            "category": {
                "uri": "/categories/20fe3330-80e1-4908-9f57-5b7ef575b197",
                "parent": "Food & Drink",
                "name": "Groceries"
            },
            "amount": "35.82",
            "debit": true
        },
        {
            "category": {
                "uri": "/categories/20fe3330-80e1-4908-9f57-5b7ef575b197",
                "parent": "Food & Drink",
                "name": "Groceries"
            },
            "amount": "12.15",
            "debit": true
        },
        {
            "category": {
                "uri": "/categories/20fe3330-80e1-4908-9f57-5b7ef575b197",
                "parent": "Food & Drink",
                "name": "Groceries"
            },
            "amount": "4.19",
            "debit": true
        },
        {
            "category": {
                "uri": "/categories/20fe3330-80e1-4908-9f57-5b7ef575b197",
                "parent": "Food & Drink",
                "name": "Groceries"
            },
            "amount": "34.11",
            "debit": true
        },
        {
            "category": {
                "uri": "/categories/20fe3330-80e1-4908-9f57-5b7ef575b197",
                "parent": "Food & Drink",
                "name": "Groceries"
            },
            "amount": "3.36",
            "debit": true
        },
        {
            "category": {
                "uri": "/categories/20fe3330-80e1-4908-9f57-5b7ef575b197",
                "parent": "Food & Drink",
                "name": "Groceries"
            },
            "amount": "11.32",
            "debit": true
        }
    ],
    "Restaurants": [
        {
            "category": {
                "uri": "/categories/15147702-8227-4ee8-8b05-d2e8d532bd0a",
                "parent": "Food & Drink",
                "name": "Restaurants"
            },
            "amount": "18.43",
            "debit": true
        }
    ]
}
```

All I want this data to be in similar to something like

```
{
    "Groceries": 1234.12, # (1234.12 is madeup value for now)added values for all Groceries transaction
    "Restaurents": 18.42
}
```

I am using [Lodash](http://lodash.com/docs#reduce) to do this, my code looks like

```
var mapped = _.reduce(data, function(result, num, key){
  var sum = 0.0;
  sum = _.reduce(num, function(sum, n){
      console.log(key + ':' + parseFloat(n.amount));
      return sum + parseFloat(n.amount);
  });
  result[key] = sum;
  return result;
}, {})
```

and the result i get is

```
"{
    "Groceries": "[object Object]19.154.216.0828.4835.8212.154.1934.113.3611.32",
    "Restaurants": {
        "category": {
            "uri": "/categories/15147702-8227-4ee8-8b05-d2e8d532bd0a",
            "parent": "Food & Drink",
            "name": "Restaurants"
        },
        "amount": "18.43",
        "debit": true
    }
}"
```

What is that I am doing incorrect here?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

From the [docs](http://lodash.com/docs#reduce):

> Reduces a collection to a value which is the accumulated result of running each element in the collection through the callback, where each successive callback execution consumes the return value of the previous execution. If accumulator is not passed, the first element of the collection will be used as the initial accumulator value

So you should either provide an initial value or parse `sum` since it is a `String` object, I would suggest giving an initial value since it doesn't make sense to parse it each time past the first.

So you could do:

```
var s = _.reduce(num, function(sum, n){
  return sum + parseFloat(n.amount);
}, 0);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
var restaurants = {
    "Restaurants": [
        {
            "category": {
                "name": "Restaurants"
            },
            "amount": "88.91"
        },
        {
            "category": {
                "name": "Restaurants"
            },
            "amount": "58.14"
        }]};

var groceries = {
    "Groceries": [
        {
            "category": {
                "name": "Groceries"
            },
            "amount": "58.41"
        },
        {
            "category": {
                "name": "Groceries"
            },
            "amount": "85.14"
        }]};

function reduce_category(collection) {
    return _.reduce(collection, function (memo, entry) { 
        return memo += parseFloat(entry.amount, 10);
    }, 0);
}

console.log((function reduce_collection(collection) {
    var sum = _.reduce(collection, function (memo, entry) {
        return memo += reduce_category(entry[_.first(_.keys(entry))]);
    }, 0);

    return (Math.round(sum * 100) / 100).toFixed(2);
}([restaurants, groceries]))) // => 290.60
```

[Fiddle.](http://jsfiddle.net/UnGWN/)